# Need SoapAPI transfered to RestAPI, is there someting available? What does it look like?

Tags: compatibility, deepsecurity

I need to know how Automation Deep Security via RestAPI: Agent Upgrade is possible?

Analogous to this SoapAPI command:        DSMWebServiceConnection.WebProxy.softwareApplyToHosts($hosts.ID,$software.version, $DSMWebServiceConnection.SessionID)

Is there something available for RestAPI? What does it look like?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's only in SOAP, no related REST API available yet.
https://automation.deepsecurity.trendmicro.com/article/20_0/api-reference/
https://automation.deepsecurity.trendmicro.com/legacy-rest/20_0/index.html?env=onprem#overview

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).